# How can I prevent the body object slipping through the clothing object?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

When I model cloth separately and rig them to the same rig as character I have a lot of sliding - the cloth uses solidify to thicken them, but the "body" mesh still slips out of the clothing (through them, not using cloth simulation).

Just to clarify - In the picture it's not rigged yet.
Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For this to work nicely you have to either:

- have the clothes as one mesh with the skin for good results with automatic weighting
- create the weights in Maya with Geodesic Voxel Binding
- weight just the skin, then copy (project) the weights with *Data Transfer modifier* to the clothes. This way they won't slide (hopefully)

  [image]
- create a shell around the clothes and skin, rig the shell with armature, drive both the skin and clothes inside the shell through *Mesh Deform modifier*

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that your topology on the clothes is different enough from the body underneath that parts poke through, then try the following:

1. Make the topology of the clothing more similar to the body
2. Use thicker solidify or subsurface
3. Use a shrinkwrap modifier on the clothing to keep it above the surface
4. Instead of weighting the body and clothing, instead make a simpler deform cage around them. Have that be driven by your armature, and then have the clothes and body use the Mesh Deform modifier with the cage. This will also make setting up your weights much easier.