# Weight painting issues with Rigify?

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, weight-painting, rigify

So I made this character but every time I try to rig the clothes it doesn't work, the base, hair, eyes and pupils work fine but everything else wants to pull on itself....how can I fix it? Thanks!! This is the file: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get decent weights on clothing, especially tight-ish clothing like you're showing, is via a data transfer modifier from your body.  Select vertex data, vertex groups, from nearest face interpolated, nominate your properly weighted body as the target, hit generate data layers, apply the modifier, and then ctrl-p parent it to your body's armature using (no-description) armature deform.

A very good alternative to this is to use a surface deform modifier instead.  Nominate your body as the target, bind, and you should be good to go, even without parenting to the armature.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be using the mask modifier, which lets you animate the visibility of some parts of the mesh (using vertex groups).

For more advanced options you can search in this site with key words as "cloth" and "rig", to get al lot of results, like this:

[How can I prevent the body object slipping through the clothing object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50456/how-can-i-prevent-the-body-object-slipping-through-the-clothing-object)

Comment: Thanks, how would I use the mask modifier to attach it to the rig? i'm not sure why it keeps doing that...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of 'gotchas' with rigging in Blender that I've found through stack overflow, web searching, and tearing my hair out.  What I would suggest before going too far is to make sure to apply scale, rotation, and location on clothing mesh.  Also apply scale, rotation, and location on the rig.  I wept many tears before I discovered that.